# CSS/Javascript: How to draw minimal border around an inline element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Consider the following HTML:

```
<p>This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which <span>may get 
wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser.
I would like to be able to draw a minimal</span> box round the span</p>
```

I would like to draw a minimal border round the span.

That is:

- If the span is rendered on a single line, the border is equivalent to setting a CSS style of border: 1px solid black;
- If the span is rendered on multiple lines, the border is drawn around the outermost edges of the span, not between the lines which it crosses. This is equivalent to setting a CSS background color on the span, and drawing the line around the edges of the highlighted area.

I am fairly confident this cannot be done with raw CSS alone (in the second case). Solutions involving javascript libraries, or those which are Firefox-specific, are acceptable.

This is a mock-up of how the second scenario should look:

[image: Second scenario mock-up]

Comment: can u upload a sample screenshot of the what the 2 scenarios should look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider adding an outline, not border http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/z9THQ/

```
span {
  outline: 2px solid black;   
}
```

Firefox draws outline between lines. There is a workarond: http://jsfiddle.net/z9THQ/2/

```css
.wrapped {
   outline: 2px solid black;
}

.wrapped span {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<p>
   This is a potentially large paragraph of text, which 
      <span class="wrapped"><span> 
        may get wrapped onto several lines when displayed in the browser. I would like to be able to draw a minimal
      </span></span> 
   box round the span
</p>
```

Comment: Didn't know it was that simple. +1

Comment: This does not address the second case as it draws a line between subsequent rows of text within the span (see illustration now added above).

Comment: Fair enough. It's a bit messy but it does the right thing in pure CSS, so answer accepted!