# How to deal with non-rectangular sections of multiline inline text?

Tags: javascript, css

How do you get a nice outline? This is similar to the question:

[CSS/Javascript: How to draw minimal border around an inline element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706091/css-javascript-how-to-draw-minimal-border-around-an-inline-element)

However, the accepted solution to that question results in jagged textboxes, as seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/z9THQ/2/

```
/* p {
    text-align: justify;
} */
.wrapped {
   outline: 2px solid black;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.wrapped span {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Even with justified text, the right edge is still jagged; it should look like a single line, like in the image below.

[image]

A pure CSS solution would be ideal, but if Javascript is necessary, that would be fine too.

A related symptom which a solution would ideally solve is the fact that the :hover attribute is not activated by the region in between two lines of text. Ideally, the whole section should feel like a text-area, only it is non-rectangular since it is inline with other text.